# how to stop durandal / jquery stripping out script tags from views?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, durandal

I know there are better patterns but in this case there's some legacy code that we'd like to move to a view.  This html has a

```
<script src="binding.js"></script>
```

that needs to run after the page renders and displays.

I hoped to do this with a `<script src="">` tag, but the tag seems to be getting stripped out.

How do we either get the script tag to render, or do a work-around with durandal?

Example html:

```
<div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/stylesheet1.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/stylesheet2.css"/>
    <header>
        <h1>heading</h1>
        <h2>sub heading</h2>
    </header>

    <section>
    </section>

    <footer>              
    </footer>
    <script src="dobinding.js"></script>    
</div>
```

This is helpful:

```
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* use a custom KnockOut binding for this.

Here's a really simple binding - keep in mind this is just an idea:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.script = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var scriptName = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).html("<script src='" + scriptName + "'></script>");
    }
};
```

In your view (.html file):

```
<div data-bind="script:'dobinding.js'"></div>
```

I tested this, and I found that the script is indeed injected, parsed, and executed, but it doesn't stay loaded in the DOM.  That may or may not be an issue for you.

Seems that stripping the  tags may be a Durandal-specific thing.  I haven't figured out the cause yet, but I'll update if I get a chance to dig into it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the behaviour.  I'll try your idea out.  ty.

Comment: how did you verify that the script injected?  An attribute on the DOM Element in Chrome Dev Tools?  The script just needs to execute.

Comment: I put some alerts in the script and they executed.  I used Chrome Dev Tools to verify that the script tag was *not* in the DOM.  To your point, maybe the tag itself wasn't injected into the main DOM, but it had to be injected into the view's DIV, because that's how the binding works - setting the html content directly `$(element).html(...);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the durandal view composition engine only uses the first html element in a view and ignores everything else. So if your script tag is outside the main container in your view I think it gets dropped.

Can you post some html/js for review?

Comment: example included. I tried the script tag inside and outside the div too.

Comment: Hmm perhaps you can't reference an external script file from there then. What's in the script file, can you just reference it from the main html page?

Comment: not without a rewrite.  There's manual stuff going on.  Would prefer to leave it as is for now.

Comment: Your options really depend on what the script file is doing. Have you considered loading the script as a module using requirejs?

Comment: Yes.  That's preprocessed though.  jquery stuff will fail because DOM isn't built yet.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not already, you could wrap whatever is going on inside the script in a function (let's call it doBindings) and then embed the script in your index.html file (or equivalent), alongside Knockout, JQuery etc.

Then, in whatever view you need to get that code running in, add a viewAttached method to the view model and make the call to doBindings:

```
activate: function() {
   ...
}
viewAttached: function() {
   doBindings();
}
```

That will invoke the function when the view is loaded and the DOM is accessible.

Solution here: [Insert script tag in Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398383), but an answer here would have saved me some additional searching, so added here too.