# Load Adsense in Durandal

Tags: adsense, durandal

I'm using Durandal to make a Single-Page Application. Is there a way to add Adsense code into the view/model? 
I'm currently using iframe's to add the ads into the views. My concern is that this could violate Google's terms and conditions.

Comment: Normally, you just put the script tags in the HTML, right?  Durandal/RequireJS has a habit of stripping script elements from the view, but you may be able to get around with something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15958430/91189

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the script using Knockout, but have you tried using Durandal's Composition to include an HTML page?

Example:

```
<div>
  <div data-bind="compose: 'views/adsense.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Inspired from docs here: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/