# Insert script tag in Durandal

Tags: javascript, tags, durandal

I am a bit struggling with what should be an easy task.
I want to insert a script tag inside a div tag. The problem is that Durandal (for a reason that I still need to understand) seems to ignore those tags. 
This problem has been described here, but the solution proposed there does not work for me.
[how to stop durandal / jquery stripping out script tags from views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952893/how-to-stop-durandal-jquery-stripping-out-script-tags-from-views)

Isn't there a simple way to tell Durandal to please interpret my script tags? 
This is becoming very frustrating, and besides the above question, I couldn't find anything on the web about this.

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I do to get this to work.
Inside the parent tag, I use a compose binding like so:

```
<td>
     <!-- ko compose: { view: 'views/homearea', model: 'viewmodels/homearea' } -->
     <!-- /ko-->
</td>
```

Inside my view, I have something like this:

```
<div id="homearea" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;">    
</div>
```

And inside the model, in the viewAttached method, I can put my custom javascript.

```
define(function () {

    var viewAttached = function () {
        $('#homearea').myFunction();
    };

    var vm = {
        viewAttached: viewAttached
    };
    return vm;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this. It was the [viewAttached method](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/) (see bottom of page) that I've spent all morning looking for ... nice one :)