# How can i run a script in a compose page

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I am trying to execute a script in a composed page without success.

Here is what i have sofar

Parent page

```
<div data-bind="compose:pagename"></div>
```

Page to be composed

```
<!-- HTML5 -->
<script>
    alert("Hallo");
</script>
<div>Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Durandal strips out the script tags. It has a good reason for doing this. The reason is that you almost certainly don't need to have script tags being composed into your view. What you're trying to accomplish is almost certainly better off in a custom binding, in the view model, or in a separate module or service that you import into your view model.

May I ask what you're actually trying to accomplish? I may be able to make a recommendation.

If, though, you are positive you need to do this, you can use the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958430/1536085).